# prerequisites for understanding game theory

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

I am from programming background but with very limited knowledge of maths.

I am very much eager to learn and apply [game theory](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/224893/game-theory) to understand dynamics of International Politics and economics. But I am facing difficulties to understand the maths involved in it.

So,

1. What are **prerequisites for understanding the math in the game theory**?
2. What are the authentic sources to understand game theory mathematically and 
   and **its application in the international politics and economics**?

Comment: There is a difference between the requisites to *master* something and to *understand* it. The latter is a sensible goal, while the first not so much.

Answer (score 4):

As @JordanMahar mentions, Fudenberg and Tirole is the standard graduate-level text. But I would start with ***Game Theory for Applied Economists*** by **Gibbons**. It is very readable.

Prerequisites for Gibbons are minimal. A little algebra and probability will do just fine.

Answer (score 3):

In economics, the classic source for game theory is:

Fudenberg, D. and Tirole, J. (1991). [Game Theory](http://www.amazon.ca/Game-Theory-Drew-Fudenberg/dp/0262061414/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1369889236&sr=8-1&keywords=game+theory+tirole)

At least with Game Theory applied to economics, you can begin with a minimal knowledge of mathematics (applied calculus and some set theory will usually suffice).

Answer (score 3):

1. **Secondary-school math.** And since game theory is essentially math, along the way you'll learn more math.
2. Ken Binmore's [*Playing for Real: A Text on Game Theory*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/456183.Playing_for_Real) is suitable for *undergraduates* and doesn't get heavily mathematical at all.

> - What is game theory about?
> - **How do I apply game theory?**
> - Why is game theory right?

There's even a marker in the margin in places where you're allowed to skip some of the math and move on to the next bit.

> It isn't easy to write in a light-hearted style when presenting mathematical material, but I did my best.

I think he did an excellent job.